# how to create new file, file name incremental

Tags: java, groovy, katalon-studio

i have written codes to generate random ID and store to file. then send the data which data contains the stored ID.
Then I set it to loop 3 times.
The data sent sucessfully 3 times, but there is only one file and contains LAST ID only.
I wanted to have 3 files, named 1,2,3.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
//test data using dynamic Id at order Id
String RandomOrderId = CustomKeywords.'test.RandomStringUUID.getUuid'()
println(RandomOrderId)

//store the OrderId to file
def OrderId = new File(RunConfiguration.getProjectDir() + "/Data Files/OrderId.txt")
OrderId .newWriter().withWriter { it << RandomOrderId }
println OrderId.text

def exceldata = CustomKeywords.'test.excelfile.ReadExcelData'('Data Files/1.xlsx', 'testdata', 'Test case1', 'Json Data 1')
exceldata = exceldata.replace("<OrderId>", OrderId.text)
        
Order.Message('message',exceldata)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem that `File.newWriter()` overwrites content of the file.

replace this line:

```
OrderId.newWriter().withWriter { it << RandomOrderId }
```

with the following one:

```
OrderId.newWriter(true).withWriter { it << RandomOrderId << '\n' }
```

or with:

```
OrderId.withWriterAppend{ it << RandomOrderId << '\n' }
```

or with:

```
OrderId.append( RandomOrderId + '\n' )
```

read more about file methods here:
http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html

Comment: i tried this OrderId.newWriter(true).withWriter { it << RandomOrderId << '\n' } the result is still one file, content has appended data. how do i overwrite the old data? I read the BufferedWriter ref doc, could not find a suitable one.

Comment: one file is fine. @daggett

Comment: move `for` loop inside the `newWriter(false).withWriter{ ... }` closure